# How to take n number of arrays, and set them as individual columns in a grander array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I begin with an n number of arrays. I'm going to define a few as an example.

```
X = ([1,2,3,4})
Y = ([5,6,7,8])
Z = ([3,6,7,8])
```

How do I create another array that will have each of my beginning arrays (X, Y, and Z) as columns? The final array will look like this:

```
1 5 3
2 6 6
3 7 7
4 8 8
```

Comment: try `column_stack!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try like this:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([1,2,3,4])
Y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
Z = np.array([3,6,7,8])
a = np.concatenate((X[:,np.newaxis],Y[:,np.newaxis],Z[:,np.newaxis]),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not big fan of third party libraries, so this is an answer that doesn't use `numpy`:

```
>>> X = ([1,2,3,4])
>>> Y = ([5,6,7,8])
>>> Z = ([3,6,7,8])
# timeit.timeit 0.30220915000000004

>>> output = [[X[i], Y[i], Z[i]] for i in range(len(X))]
# timeit.timeit 1.677441058
>>> print(output)
[[1, 5, 3], [2, 6, 6], [3, 7, 7], [4, 8, 8]]

>>> columns = "\n".join([" ".join([str(n) for n in i]) for i in output])
# timeit.timeit 5.729952549999999
>>> print(columns)
1 5 3
2 6 6
3 7 7
4 8 8

>>> for i in range(len(X)):
...    print(X[i], Y[i], Z[i])
1 5 3
2 6 6
3 7 7
4 8 8
# timeit.timeit 1.2027191299999984 without print
```

Using `numpy`:

```
>>> X = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> Y = np.array([5,6,7,8])
>>> Z = np.array([3,6,7,8])
# timeit.timeit 4.819555767999999

>>> output = np.concatenate((X[:, np.newaxis], Y[:, np.newaxis], Z[:, np.newaxis]), axis=1)
# timeit.timeit 4.175194263
>>> print(output)
[[1 5 3]
 [2 6 6]
 [3 7 7]
 [4 8 8]]

>>> columns = "\n".join([" ".join([str(n) for n in i]) for i in output])
# timeit.timeit 22.564187487
>>> print(columns)
1 5 3
2 6 6
3 7 7
4 8 8
```

On comments (`#`) I wrote the time it takes to execute each section of the code using `timeit.timeit` so you could take your own conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

There is an in-built function called [`column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) for this purpose.

```
np.column_stack((X, Y, Z))
# array([[1, 5, 3],
#        [2, 6, 6],
#        [3, 7, 7],
#        [4, 8, 8]])
```

**Alternatively** you can use `vstack` and then transpose

```
arr = np.vstack((X,Y,Z)).T
```